# Android : NoClassDefFoundError including java project on android library

Tags: android, include, project, noclassdeffounderror

Good morning,

I am developing a system with an android client application that communicate with a java server. Some element of my application must be reusable in the future.

So for the moment, I have 3 projects (I don't begin to code the server) :

- GlobalLibrary : A java project that contains class used by server and client
- AndroidClientLibrary : An android library that contains code reusable for other android client applications. It include GlobalLibrary in Java Build Path -> Projects, Java Build Path -> Order and Export and Project references. Option Is Library is tickled in Android properties
- MyAndroidClient : An android client application that include AndroidClientLibrary in Android properties.

I encounter problems using class defined on GlobalLibrary on running MyAndroidClient : E/AndroidRuntime(8748): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.guirak.GlobalLibrary.AGlobalClass
I don"t encounter problem running  MyAndroidClient using class defined on AndroidClientLibrary.

I tried using a jar file generated on Global Library and include it on Java Build Path -> Librairies of MyAndroidClient and AndroidClientLibrary.
I tried to include GlobalLibrary in Java Build Path -> Projects, Java Build Path -> Order and Export and Project references of MyAndroidClient

Nothing of these work....

Can someone help me for these problem?

Thank you for advance and sorry for my English level...

Comment: Is your library checked on the import/export tab ? And btw, which IDE are you using ?

Comment: I'm working with Eclipse Luna. Yes, my library is checked on the import/export tab.

Comment: Does the class that could not be found contain a main function?